# How do I make two columns' widths fit their content and three columns' widths divide the remaining space up evenly in a table?

Tags: css

I have a table with 5 columns, 2 contain buttons containing translatable text and the other 3 contain URLs. I need the 2 button columns to fit their contents and the other 3 columns to share the remaining horizontal space with extra long data being broken into multiple rows of text.

Also Bootstrap is available to me.

Right now I'm using (unsuccessully):

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th.dataColumn, td.dataColumn {
    width: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

th.buttonColumn, td.buttonColumn {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

When I remove "table-layout: fixed" from my CSS file the table then is wider than the space it is supposed to be containing.

Comment: if you will add code pen it will help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own:

```
th.mainColumn, td.mainColumn {
  width: 32%;
  max-width: 1px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

th.buttonColumn, td.buttonColumn {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 2%;
}
```